# Can you pick up Thor's hammer?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

In the Avengers Age of Ultron they make a big deal about picking up Thor's hammer. When they are on the aircarrier the hulk tries to pick it up and he can't... But the aircarrier (or earlier a table) does support it? Does that mean it only works on "living things"? Because when you follow this logic of "it can be supported", then you should be able to pick it up with a backpack or something else? Right?

So can you pick up the hammer as unrighteous person using a bag or something as support?

Comment: Supporting it and lifting it are two very different actions. A solid object can support the hammer, but an unworthy person wouldn't be able to lift the solid object supporting the hammer.

Comment: Think King Arthur... it doesn't take strength to lift, it needs 'righteousness'.

Comment: @onewho Thanks for the respons. I get that only the righteous can pick it up and a table supports it. My point/question... Following the "it can be supported" rule ... When you use a bag to support the hammer, can you, as unrighteous person, walk off with the hammer?

Comment: @Tetsujin see prev comment

Comment: @stevenvanc As I stated originally a solid object supporting the hammer can't be lifted by an unworthy person, this reasoning would work for a backpack; while the backpack may be supporting the hammer, an unworthy person still cannot lift the backpack and walk off with the hammer.

Comment: @stevenvanc - you're trying to pick holes in extremely well-established **folk lore** - Arthurian legend being approximately 1000 years old. [The legend of Thor is older still, but generally less well-known outside of the Marvel universe adaptations]

Comment: And yet whoever was flying the aircarrier was still able to take off with the hammer on board...  So, I guess as long as the force that seeks to move the hammer is not generated by a living being?  I can't pick up the backpack containing the hammer with my arms, but I could probably lift it with a forklift and drive away?

Comment: @Steve-O - perhaps the restriction is upon "wielding" the hammer?  Otherwise if the hammer came to rest on top of someone, it would burrow through their chests, leaving a hammer-shaped death-hole in their torso.  That would cover it being moved along with or supported by the surroundings.

Comment: @Tetsujin Come one, I doubt that the giant flying air carrier that led to this question, was part of the folklore. And I'm being respectful, I'm not picking holes. I'm wondering, that's all.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet That would make a terrible mess when Thor "calls" his hammer... But what would happen, if you're right and the hammer wouldn't crush him, when he uses his hand to pick it off him self? That would trigger the "wield" state of the hammer?

Comment: I think it's more to do with the intent. Hulk and the other Avengers either want to use it as a weapon, or have their egos inflated by being able to lift the "godly" object. The Heli-carrier pilot had the intent of moving the S.H.I.E.L.D personnel from one place to another, rather than make off with Mjolinir. An elevator, table or coat hook have no intent with the hammer.  If Thor was to put it in _your_ backpack and you didn't know, you may be able to move it as you have no intent with it. If it wasn't your bag, you'd likely not be able to move it as there is ill intent there. All speculation

Comment: @gabe3886 - "If Thor was to put it in your backpack" - don't give my daughter any ideas......

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I doubt many people's daughters need to be given any ideas at all when it comes to Thor

Comment: @gabe3886 - "Dad.... I TOTALLY need a bigger backpack this year....."

Comment: If the hammer were on a table as support, would I be able to dig under the table causing it to fall along with the hammer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's magic. Intent is important. SHIELD tried to move the dirt pile that the hammer landed on in Nevada. Didn't work. So they built around it.

Tony couldn't lift it using the Iron Man gauntlet, which is much like your backpack concept.

And Tony and Steve argue that machines are excluded from  the rule,  like elevators and the Vision. Thor says otherwise.

The presented evidence is overwhelming that a backpack would not be a loophole.

Comment: It's magic. You know, in this context, that's actually a good explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, it's sufficiently advanced science.

Comment: Thors mom will scold you for saying that